# How to unlock a Windows 10 pc through remote shell

Tags: windows-10, ssh

I sometimes run into the problem where users need to access a certain windows pc, but I don't want to tell them the password. How would I unlock the pc through ssh session from a (obviously) remote location?

Note: This has to be through the shell, anything else won't work.

Comment: I am 98% certain that this is not possible. the security implications of such a capability are legion.